# Why my block is not overwriting the magento core block?

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I am trying to overwrite a magento's core block but it shows an error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addToChildGroup() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento_new/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 815
```

here is my modules `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Pfay_MyProduct>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</Pfay_MyProduct>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                 <product_view>Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
         </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

and my `view.php` is

```
<?php

class Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
    public function canEmailToFriend()
    {
            return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong in this ?

Comment: Please try to override class as per answer and create the file as per the below path and name

Comment: I am not sure your block rewrite is connected to the error.
The rewrite itself looks OK. Try to find all calls for addToChildGroup fucntion from layout XMLs and make sure their blocks types inherits from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code

In `config.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <modules>
    <Pfay_MyProduct>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Pfay_MyProduct>
  </modules>
  <global>        
    <blocks>
      <myproduct>
        <class>Pfay_MyProduct_Block</class>
      </myproduct>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
               <product_view>Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

And Crete file on Pfay\MyProduct\Block\Catalog\Product\View.php

```
<?php
class Pfay_MyProduct_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
   public function canEmailToFriend()
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keyul for quick reply, I already tried this, but nothing happen, still got the error message

Comment: have you flush your cache after installing this module?

Comment: yeah I flushed the cache but no luck

Comment: where you put your code in local or core code pool?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12842/with-waseem

join this so we can discuss on chat

Comment: ofcourse in local codepool

Comment: so what was the correction to make at the end ?